# ( Angularjs Javascript) Variable assign

Tags: javascript, angularjs, variables, assign

im newbie , i have a questions. I write simple code using promise angularjs .

```
var data = {"collection": "installation",
              "timeframe": {
                          "start": moment(date_from).format('YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss'),
                          "end": moment(date_to).format('YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss')
                }};
  var install_all = Insight.installations(data);
  data['filters'] = [{"property_name": "os", "operator": "eq", "property_value": "android"}];
  var filter_android = data;
  var install_android = Insight.installations(filter_android);
  data['filters'][0]['property_value'] = 'ios';
  var filter_ios = data;
  var install_ios = Insight.installations(filter_ios);
  data['filters'][0]['property_value'] = 'windowsphone';
  var filter_wp = data;
  var install_windowsphone = Insight.installations(filter_wp);
  $q.all({'install_all': install_all, 'install_android':install_android,
    'install_ios':install_ios,'install_windowsphone':install_windowsphone})
    .then(function(data){
      $scope.install_all = data['install_all']['result'];
      $scope.install_android = data['install_android']['result'];
      $scope.install_ios = data['install_ios']['result'];
      $scope.install_windowsphone = data['install_windowsphone']['result'];

    }, function(errors){
      console.log("The request failed with response" + errors.status);
    });
```

I wish when i run, script call 4 api different filters. But when i check console log , all api same filters like this:

```
{u'filters': [{u'operator': u'eq', u'property_name': u'os', u'property_value': u'windowsphone'}], u'collection': u'installation', u'timeframe': {u'start': u'2015-07-04T00:00:00', u'end': u'2015-07-04T00:00:00'}}
"POST /admin/api/queries/count HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

Why variable sames ? I dont understand . Sorry about my english

Answer (score 1):

You are overwriting the `data` filter. You always modify the same object. Filter-ios, filter-android, filter-wp are references to the same object. You need to make a copy before you modify it.

Comment: I make a copy but not success . I dont know why ? You have a example ? Assign var javascript different than python or php

Comment: An assignment of a variable in javascript is the same as in any other language. The referencw of the origin and the new variable name are the same. Assign is not a copy! If you change the original then you also change the new variable. In angular you use `angular.copy`.

Comment: Maybe you should read the chapter about object references in javascript again.